# Using the Lift web session from Lift rest session

Tags: scala, lift

I've got a Lift web application where I want to provide a csv download link. The csv is provided by a Lift rest service.

No problem setting up this. However; in order for this to work secure and smootly I need to use the already established authenticated web session.

This is my current rest authentication with my other rest services. Does there exist any role for the web user that I can put in the ???'s below; or am I missing the point completely?

```
LiftRules.authentication = HttpBasicAuthentication("lift") {
  case (`webshopUser`, `webshopPwd`, _) =>
    userRoles(webshopRole :: Nil)
    true
  case (`mailingListUser`, `mailingListPwd`, _) =>
    userRoles(mailingListRole :: Nil)
    true
}

LiftRules.httpAuthProtectedResource.append {
  case Req("rest" :: "mailingLists" :: _, _, _) => Full(mailingListRole)
  case Req("rest" :: "mamberships" :: "year" :: _, _, _) => ???
  case Req("rest" :: "memberships" :: _, _, _) => Full(webshopRole)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The role is just an arbitrary permission that allows you to control access to your resources. Somewhere in your application you've defined `webshopRole` and `mailingListRole` as variables which implement [`net.liftweb.http.auth.Role`](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/scaladocs/index.html). To protect that second request, you'd need to decide if:

1. You only want to grant access to one of the two users accounts.
   Then, let's say you want to allow allow the account defined by
   `webshopUser`. In that case you would use `Full(webshopRole)`.
2. You want both users to have access. In this case, you would define a new role similar to how `webshopRole` was defined, and for this example - we'll call it `csvRole`. Then you'd add that role to the `HttpBasicAuthentication` rule, like: `userRoles(webshopRole :: csvRole :: Nil)`. And in the mapping, you'd use: `Full(csvRole)`

Comment: Well, neither actually. Sorry I weren't more clear. I've got a web application part with a Person class that extends MegaProtoUser. This is the basis for the web authenticated users. I want to use those users and the web session they are already logged into.

Comment: The user and the roles are not tied entirely together. Users can have one or more roles, and roles can be assigned to more than one user. Users identify the individual and Roles define what they have permission to do. In your case, the user identified by `webshopUser` is assigned a single role of `webshopRole` and access to `/rest/memberships` is restricted to users who have that role. What I was getting at was depending on how you want to restrict, you can either add a new role for your existing users - or, you can re-use one if you only need that user to have access.

Comment: My problem is that I see now we to relate MegaProtoUser to roles.